# Access local machine IP from docker in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

So I am running Jenkins in a docker image on mac with the following command:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name jenkins -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`

So I can access from my local machine using localhost:8080, but from Jenkins I need to configure a plugin that requires to access an app on my local machine, but no idea how I can do that, so I was reading that I should use `--network=host` but with that I can't access localhost:8080 anymore.

Any idea what I am missing, I need to be able to connect Jenkins with an app on localhost and be able to access Jenkins as well.

Comment: `--network` is only supported for Linux. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: Not really, it says that I should use "host.docker.internal" which AFAIK it's to access the docker container, and I need the other way around

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into this problem the post linked in the comment by user @ycr worked for me

> --network is only supported for Linux. Does this answer your question? stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/… – ycr

Since OP seems to dismiss the viability of this solution I think it might be usefull to share my experience.
I had a similar issue to OP in that I was trying to connect to a gitea server running on `localhost:3000` (not dockerized) using the gitea plugin installed on jenkins which itself *was* running from a docker container.

When trying to add the gitea address `http://localhost:3000` in the gitea plugin config I was initially getting the error
`Could not communicate with server: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

Adding the `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` flag to the `docker run` command and setting the gitea server addres to `http://host.docker.internal:3000` in the gitea plugin configuration solved the issue for me.